# How can I get IE7 to overlay another image on hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get IE to overlay an image when it is hovered

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<header>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="logotestIE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</header>
<body>
<ul class="letterlist">
    <li><img class="grayscale" src="http://mdsystem.com/image/new_start/logos/logo_anadolu.gif" /></li>
    <li><img class="grayscale" src="http://mdsystem.com/image/new_start/logos/logo_aston_martin.gif" /></li>
</ul>




</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mFwnQ/

Any hints?

Edit:
ok, I formulated the question badly: I want to hover an image. on hover it should be positioned on top of the next one 
right now the hovered image is positioned underneath the next image

Comment: over lay an image on hover? do you mean replace the bottom image with the top image?

Comment: nothing to do with IE. this is general javascript/css/dom stuff. Try using jquery. it makes such things trivial.

Comment: ok, I formulated the question badly: I want to hover an image. on hover it should be on top of the next one
right now the hovered image is underneath the next image

Comment: P.S. `<header>` tags are **NOT** a replacement for `<head>` tags!  They are completely different things.

Comment: @simplex123 does my answer help you?  Do you need assistance?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to create a sprite. In any photo/image software (photoshop) take both images and place them in the same file, one under the other.

**Example:**

[image: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/sprites/dw-logo-sprite.jpg]

then you create an element, and give it a background of the image, and position it to show only the image you wish to show before hover.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="button"> </a>
```

**CSS**

```
#button
{
  width:191px;
  height:151px;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  background-image:url(dw-logo-sprite.jpg);
  background-position:191px 0;
}
```

then add `:hover` to the element and position it to the next image

```
#button:hover { background-position:0 0; }
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mFwnQ/2/**

**Source: http://davidwalsh.name/css-sprites**

Comment: no, sorry. this isn't it. I'm trying to get this effect (http://jsfiddle.net/Xu5gU/) to work in IE7. I figured out, that IE doesn't support CSS3 transforms, so I used the proprietary filter from microsoft. the problem is: when I hover the image, it gets bigger (what I want), but the hovered image isn't displayed in it's full size, but gets cut off at the edges. I simply want the same effect in IE like I have it in Firefox or any other modern browser